# Converting Activity To Fragment

Tags: android, pdf, android-fragments

i want to Convert My Activity To fragment can any One help to Convert Activity to Fragment..i have created Pdf
reader (Click On Button It Will Open Pdf File In Another Activty using pdfviwer.jar  library..and I want When I click On Button Pdf  Open On Same Screen on Right Side )
i need Help please Solve My Problem

i m posting my Activity

maiinActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "ABC.pdf");
    try
    {
        in = assetManager.open("ABC.pdf");
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyPdfViewerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getFilesDir()+"/ABC.pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
    /* 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/ABC.pdf"),
            "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);*/
}
 });

}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
  }
```

PdfviwerActivty.java

```
public class MyPdfViewerActivity extends PdfViewerActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.left_arrow; }
public int getNextPageImageResource() { return R.drawable.right_arrow; }
public int getZoomInImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_in; }
public int getZoomOutImageResource() { return R.drawable.zoom_out; }
public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() { return R.layout.pdf_file_password; }
public int getPdfPageNumberResource() { return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber; }
public int getPdfPasswordEditField() { return R.id.etPassword; }
public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() { return R.id.btOK; }
public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() { return R.id.btExit; }
public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() { return R.id.pagenum_edit; }

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because Stack Overflow is not a code monkey recruitment hub.     Please describe the issue you are having while attempting to implement code to solve your issue.

Comment: @user3759751 Did you get your required answer? If yes please let me know how to use PDFViewer.jar with Fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try "extends FragmentActivity" instead of "extends Activity"..

Comment: I m Using PdfViewer.jar Library Then How To extends PdfViewerActivity look at my pdfViewer Activty i m So confused

Answer (score 0):

You should use FragementActivity instead of Activity and paste your ui-components into the fragment's onCreateView()-Method. For further information look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: I m Using PdfViewer.jar Library 
Then How To extends PdfViewerActivity
look at my pdfViewer Activty i m So confused

Comment: I think you can paste the source of PdfViewActivity in your fragment's class with little modification. Take a look at this: https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/blob/master/src/net/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/PdfViewerActivity.java

Comment: WhEre to Modify   please help me 
can u describe